# how to replace periodic occurrence of a array in a text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have below text file

```
      (      21.349659891       0.000000000       0.000000000 )
      (       0.000000000      21.349659891       0.000000000 )
      (       0.000000000       0.000000000      24.110175194 )


  Ex  (       -7.61882       -0.00000        0.00000 )
  Ey  (        0.00000       -7.61882        0.00000 )
  Ez  (        0.00000        0.00000       -7.04421 )
  Ex  (       -7.61882        0.00000        0.00000 )
  Ey  (       -0.00000       -7.61882        0.00000 )
  Ez  (        0.00000        0.00000       -7.04421 )
  Ex  (        3.46435        0.00000        0.00000 )
  Ey  (        0.00000        3.46435        0.00000 )
  Ez  (        0.00000        0.00000        2.88195 )
  Ex  (        3.46435        0.00000        0.00000 )
  Ey  (        0.00000        3.46435        0.00000 )
  Ez  (        0.00000        0.00000        2.88195 )
  Ex  (        4.13400        0.00000        0.00000 )
  Ey  (        0.00000        4.13400        0.00000 )
  Ez  (        0.00000        0.00000        4.12922 )
  Ex  (        4.13400        0.00000        0.00000 )
  Ey  (        0.00000        4.13400        0.00000 )
  Ez  (        0.00000        0.00000        4.12922 )
```

For rest of the files there is repetitive occurrence of Ex, Ey and Ez.

I want to update this text file as below (CLM1 deals top three lines while CLM2 is needed for rest of the text file):

```
CLM1(:,1)=21.349659891       0.000000000       0.000000000,
CLM1(:,2)=0.000000000      21.349659891       0.000000000,
CLM1(:,3)=0.000000000       0.000000000      24.110175194,
CLM2(:,1,1)=-7.61882       -0.00000        0.00000,
CLM2(:,2,1)= 0.00000       -7.61882        0.00000,
CLM2(:,3,1)= 0.00000        0.00000       -7.04421,
CLM2(:,1,2)=-7.61882        0.00000        0.00000,
CLM2(:,2,2)=-0.00000       -7.61882        0.00000,
CLM2(:,3,2)=0.00000        0.00000       -7.04421,
CLM2(:,1,3)=3.46435        0.00000        0.00000,
CLM2(:,2,3)=0.00000        3.46435        0.00000,
CLM2(:,3,3)=0.00000        0.00000        2.88195,
CLM2(:,1,4)=3.46435        0.00000        0.00000,
CLM2(:,2,4)=0.00000        3.46435        0.00000,
CLM2(:,3,4)=0.00000        0.00000        2.88195,
CLM2(:,1,5)=4.13400        0.00000        0.00000,
CLM2(:,2,5)=0.00000        4.13400        0.00000,
CLM2(:,3,5)=4.13400        0.00000        0.00000,
CLM2(:,1,6)=4.13400        0.00000        0.00000,
CLM2(:,2,6)=0.00000        4.13400        0.00000,
CLM2(:,3,6)=0.00000        0.00000        4.12922,
```

Notice that CLM2 data has periodicity as per Ex, Ey and Ez while next number (1 to 6) is occurring sequentially equal to the number of times that Ex or Ey or Ez appears (starting from 1). If Ex/Ey/Ez repeats upto 100 times then then this CLM2 will extend upto 99. In such case last three lines will be like this

```
CLM2(:,1,99)=
CLM2(:,2,99)=
CLM2(:,3,99)=
```

I am looking for a shell scrip that can do this job for me.

I tried to update the files using below script

```
 sed '/^$/d' text-file | tr -d '(' |   tr -d '(' |  sed 's/Ex/CLM2(:,1,1) = /g' | sed 's/Ey/CLM2(:,1,1) = /g' | sed 's/Ez/CLM2(:,1,1)  = /g' | sed 's/$/,/' | sed '1s/^/CLM1(:,1) = /g' |  sed '2s/^/CLM1(:,2) = /g' |  sed '3s/^/CLM1(:,3) = /g'
```

But this did not work as a loop over Ex,Ey and Ez.
I got below while using a above command

```
CLM1(:,1) =        21.349659891       0.000000000       0.000000000 ,
CLM1(:,2) =        0.000000000      21.349659891       0.000000000 ,
CLM1(:,3) =        0.000000000       0.000000000      24.110175194 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1) =          -7.61882       -0.00000        0.00000 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1) =           0.00000       -7.61882        0.00000 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1)  =           0.00000        0.00000       -7.04421 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1) =          -7.61882        0.00000        0.00000 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1) =          -0.00000       -7.61882        0.00000 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1)  =           0.00000        0.00000       -7.04421 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1) =           3.46435        0.00000        0.00000 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1) =           0.00000        3.46435        0.00000 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1)  =           0.00000        0.00000        2.88195 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1) =           3.46435        0.00000        0.00000 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1) =           0.00000        3.46435        0.00000 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1)  =           0.00000        0.00000        2.88195 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1) =           4.13400        0.00000        0.00000 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1) =           0.00000        4.13400        0.00000 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1)  =           0.00000        0.00000        4.12922 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1) =           4.13400        0.00000        0.00000 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1) =           0.00000        4.13400        0.00000 ,
      CLM2(:,1,1)  =           0.00000        0.00000        4.12922 ,
```

Comment: @astha, Also adding to what Cyrus sir mentioned, please explain your sample expected output more clearly in your question and let us know as its not clear as of now IMHO.

Comment: Dear @Cyrus and Ravinder Sir, I have updated my efforts.

Comment: What I need is mentioned under "I want to update this text file as below (CLM1 deals top three lines while CLM2 is needed for rest of the text file):"

Comment: question about input: is there leading space for CLM1? columns with tabulator or spaces?

Comment: default!! as given the original file.

Comment: You can't efficiently increment numbers in `sed`. Use `awk`.

Comment: @alecxs Yes, it will always be same. space at first line was mistakenly deleted. Not it looks okay.

Comment: Actually I could not get your query. What do you mean by "input is tab of space"?

Comment: @alecxs this is multi  spaces before first colum not a tab.

Comment: @alecxs sed '/^$/d' text-file | tr -d '(' |   tr -d '(' |  sed 's/Ex/CLM2(:,1,1) = /g' | sed 's/Ey/CLM2(:,1,1) = /g' | sed 's/Ez/CLM2(:,1,1)  = /g' | sed 's/$/,/' | sed '1s/^/CLM1(:,1) = /g' |  sed '2s/^/CLM1(:,2) = /g' |  sed '3s/^/CLM1(:,3) = /g'

Comment: I could manage it using above script but failed to make a loop. getting (:,1,1) for CLM2 while I need a patterns as per my original post

Comment: Some of the `=` in your expected output have a blank char after them (e.g. `CLM2(:,3,1)= 0.00000` while others don't (e.g. `CLM2(:,3,2)=0.00000`). If that's deliberate then explain the criteria for including that blank or not, if it's a mistake then fix your expected output.

Comment: That does not matter sir. This is a space free format.

Comment: Then you should say that in your question so we don't waste time thinking about it and coming up with code to try produce exactly the spacing you show. My answer would have been different if I hadn't been trying to preserve and reproduce your white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NF {
    if ( $1 == "(" ) {
        clm = "CLM1"
    }
    else {
        if ( seen[$1] || (clm == "CLM1") ) {
            clm = "CLM2"
            blockNr++
            lineNr = 0
            delete seen
        }
        seen[$1]++
        sub(/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+/,"")
    }

    gsub(/[[:space:]]*[()][[:space:]]*/,"")

    printf "%s(:,%d%s)=%s,\n", clm, ++lineNr, (blockNr ? "," blockNr : ""), $0
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
CLM1(:,1)=21.349659891       0.000000000       0.000000000,
CLM1(:,2)=0.000000000      21.349659891       0.000000000,
CLM1(:,3)=0.000000000       0.000000000      24.110175194,
CLM2(:,1,1)=-7.61882       -0.00000        0.00000,
CLM2(:,2,1)=0.00000       -7.61882        0.00000,
CLM2(:,3,1)=0.00000        0.00000       -7.04421,
CLM2(:,1,2)=-7.61882        0.00000        0.00000,
CLM2(:,2,2)=-0.00000       -7.61882        0.00000,
CLM2(:,3,2)=0.00000        0.00000       -7.04421,
CLM2(:,1,3)=3.46435        0.00000        0.00000,
CLM2(:,2,3)=0.00000        3.46435        0.00000,
CLM2(:,3,3)=0.00000        0.00000        2.88195,
CLM2(:,1,4)=3.46435        0.00000        0.00000,
CLM2(:,2,4)=0.00000        3.46435        0.00000,
CLM2(:,3,4)=0.00000        0.00000        2.88195,
CLM2(:,1,5)=4.13400        0.00000        0.00000,
CLM2(:,2,5)=0.00000        4.13400        0.00000,
CLM2(:,3,5)=0.00000        0.00000        4.12922,
CLM2(:,1,6)=4.13400        0.00000        0.00000,
CLM2(:,2,6)=0.00000        4.13400        0.00000,
CLM2(:,3,6)=0.00000        0.00000        4.12922,
```